# Locked Laptop blue blox enter password, completly locked pc

Tags: password

I installed ubuntu 15. 10 in an asus F553.  I set up a super user or encrypted master password which apparently I can't remember. I was using the laptop,  then turned it off,  now when i start the laptop a screen with an ''enter password" box pop ups before i can even press any key. It's all black screen with a blue box that ask for a password,  it pop ups instantly as you press the on buttom of the laptop, it is completley locked. What can I do? :S thanks in advance.

Comment: If it immediatly pops up, I think it is a BIOS or UEFI password that prevents from booting up. This is not related to UBUNTU but to the manufacturer of said BIOS or UEFI.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user enables a BIOS password, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that *HATEthePLOT* is right.

If you can boot your PC from external media (say usb) - prepare a Ubuntu image and boot the PC form it.

Select Try Ubuntu and you will boot to Live system.

After that you can access your root partition (the one that is on a HDD in the locked system).

1. Generate new password hash
   `perl -e 'print crypt("password","\$6\$saltsalt\$") . "\n"'`
2. The file you should edit is */etc/shadow* Using generated hash update password for the needed user

Now you just have to reboot the system back form your internal drive and have new password for needed user.

P.S. I do assume you know how to mount drives and do have general knowledge  of Linux system. If not I can write more dedicated instruction.

Comment: Thank you for your answers,  I'm a virgin in Linux,  just user knowledge,  the password request pops up before i can even choose the booting source...  Very strange,  ive tried with the ubuntu 15. 10 cd i burned but it wont start from it :s

Comment: Than it's bio9s, not Linux question (